# Joomla SEF URLs with Nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, joomla, url-rewriting, ngx-http-rewrite-module

```
Gentoo Linux 4.4.8-hardened
Nginx 1.10.1
MySQL 5.6.33
PHP 5.6.26
Joomla 1.5.26
```

Migration to latest Joomla is close to impossible because of the amount of custom components that have been written during 5 years.

The problem is with URLs.

Although we created menu items that link to specific pages, they still appear in index

Example:

normal link, created by menu, and this is the only link that should exist:

```
/delivery-install.html
```

but, this page is also accessible through these kinds of URLs:

```
/delivery-install
/delivery-install/
```

Right now I'm trying to avoid it with 301 redirects, but I know that it's not the right thing to do.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: All these links are not real static files, all of them are served by PHP. So the only thing you can do in nginx is redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

We have finally found a solution to this problem, and we have documented the whole process [here](http://www.itoctopus.com/all-urls-display-homepage-content-on-a-joomla-website-powered-by-nginx).

Essentially, you will need to enable cgi.fix_pathinfo and you will need to set the value of `PATH_TRANSLATED` in the `fastcgi_params` file.

The root cause of the problem is one of the much needed PHP `$_SERVER` variables is passed empty to the application by nginx.

Comment: I've just tried your solution, it didn't work out. Your problem was with all pages directing to home page, my problem is that when you access pages with `/` or `.html` it shows the same page, causing doubles, which are very very bad for SEO